# Leave link when replacing text in a cell

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace text , but i need the links to stay intact. When i replace text , its striping away the "a" tags

```
<th><a href="#">Leave Link</a> Oct 2019 <a href="#">Leave Link</a></th>

jQuery('th').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('Oct', 'OCTOBER'); 
});
```

Current result is

```
<th>Leave Link OCTOBER 2019 Leave Link</th>
```

Need result to be

```
<th><a href="#">Leave Link</a> OCTOBER 2019 <a href="#">Leave Link</a></th>
```

Thank you for the answers , lastly if i have several text changes to make , can i incorpate in same function , like so ? Or who would i do that ?

```
$('#calendar .month_header th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Oct', 'OCTOBER'); 
     return $(this).html().replace('Nov', 'NOVEMBER'); 
     return $(this).html().replace('Dec', 'DECEMBER'); 
});
```

or is the only alternative like so

```
jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Oct', 'OCTOBER');
});
jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Nov', 'NOVEMBER'); 
});
jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Dec', 'DECEMBER'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use .html instead of text

```js
const months = {
  "Oct": "OCTOBER",
  "Nov": "NOVEMBER",
  "Dec": "DECEMBER"
}

$('th').html(function() {
  const month = $(this).text().match(/(\w{3}) \d{4}/)[1];
  return $(this).html().replace(month, months[month]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="#">Leave Link</a> Oct 2019 <a href="#">Leave Link</a></th>
      <th><a href="#">Leave Link</a> Nov 2019 <a href="#">Leave Link</a></th>
      <th><a href="#">Leave Link</a> Dec 2019 <a href="#">Leave Link</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks !! i updated my question to include a question to see if i can make serveral requests in that function when the Month Name is changed dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Put the text you want to change in a `span` element.

```
<th><a href="#">Leave Link</a> <span>Oct 2019</span> <a href="#">Leave Link</a></th>
```

```
jQuery('th > span').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('Oct', 'OCTOBER'); 
});
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkorber/jnr609m7/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Jquery .text() will strip the html tags.

Please use .html() if you need to manipulate the html.

```
$('th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Oct', 'OCTOBER'); 
});
```